# Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode): Expected Flutter XXX, but found XXX

Tags: xcode, flutter

Just upgraded to flutter 3.7.3 on channel stable. Running on ios simulator works fine, but when I try to archive project:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Expected Flutter 857bd6b74c5eb56151bfafe91e7fa6a82b6fee25, but found 248290d6d50a1bf1a6a246544347c03acda867a5


Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

Flutter doctor is:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-arm64, locale fr-FR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the fix:
This issue happens when you generated a shader compilation jank. In the generated file (i.e flutter_01.sksl.json) you have to change the Flutter version. Preferably you run the SkSL warmup again with the new flutter version

Comment: Thanks! Saved me - error couldn't be googled and your answer here is the only one in the whole Internet.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you generate precompiled shaders to fix the compilation jank. Also, in the future skia will probably be replaced by impeller, which removes the need to do this.